# Validate number INTEGER on text boxes IN windows forms issue

Tags: c#, winforms

i have textbox on a windows form and i want to be insert only numbers in this textbox.i use the following c# code for that

```
private void ChildAge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    if (!int.TryParse(ChildAge.Text, out i))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Plaese enter a valid Age");
    }    
}
```

it is working, but the problem is that , after showing the Message, when i **Backspace** the content and **text box** become **null**, on that situation also this **message box shows again**.

Comment: I assume you mean that `ChildAge.Text` becomes null? Not the actual `ChildAge`?

Comment: yes. first time no problem , only when click backspace and all content remove from text box again this msgbox shows

Comment: Do a test like this 
if(!string.isNullEmpty(ChildAge.Text))
{
if (!int.TryParse(ChildAge.Text, out i))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Plaese enter a valid Age");

       }
}

Comment: erm, `(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ChildAge.Text) && !int.TryParse(ChildAge.Text, out i))`

Comment: or instead override `OnKeyPress` and cancel any presses that don't pass `char.IsDigit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a little test like bellow:

```
int i = 0;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ChildAge.Text) && 
     !int.TryParse(ChildAge.Text, out i)
  )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Age");
}
```

Comment: could use `&&` to save indentation

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Below. This works better.

```
  bool m_BackPressed = false;
    private void ChildAge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        if (!m_BackPressed)            
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(ChildAge.Text, out i))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Plaese enter a valid Age");
            } 
        }


    }

    private void ChildAge_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        m_BackPressed = (e.KeyChar.Equals((char)Keys.Back)) ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: yes. But what if user enters multiple characters and then start pressing backspace to delete all characters in textbox?